# Sort tuples based on second parameter

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples that look something like this:

```
("Person 1",10)
("Person 2",8)
("Person 3",12)
("Person 4",20)
```

What I want produced, is the list sorted in ascending order, by the second value of the tuple. So L[0] should be `("Person 2", 8)` after sorting.

How can I do this? Using Python 3.2.2 If that helps.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter to `list.sort()`:

```py
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

or, slightly faster,

```py
my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

(As with any module, you'll need to `import operator` to be able to use it.)

Comment: I've tried using `L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))` in my code, but I get a NameError, that 'operator' is not defined. Do I need to import anything special?

Comment: Did a bit of a search, need to use `import operator` to use the function. If you add that to your answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Testing with timeit.timeit (default options) there's not a huge difference between these two approaches: operator.itemgetter = 1.05µs, lambda = 1.25µs per iteration

Comment: Thanks for the my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1)) solution!! :)

Comment: If you're new to the lambda keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda

Answer (score 17):

You may also apply the `sorted` function on your list, which returns a new sorted list. This is just an addition to the [answer that Sven Marnach has given above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459231/sort-tuples-based-on-second-parameter#8459243).

```
# using *sort method*
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) 

# using *sorted function*
l = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: This is just the built-in that returns a new list. Your answer doesn't contribute anything to the ones already here, as it is clear that if you wanted a new list you would use `sorted` instead of `list.sort`.

Comment: @SamuelNde I scrolled down here because I wasn't sure if the expression worked the same for sorted so it helped me.

Comment: Yeah agreed, this helped me too

Comment: It actually does contribute, you can use `sorted` on sets but `myset.sort` results in an error. So it appears to be the more general answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
    def findMaxSales(listoftuples):
        newlist = []
        tuple = ()
        for item in listoftuples:
             movie = item[0]
             value = (item[1])
             tuple = value, movie

             newlist += [tuple]
             newlist.sort()
             highest = newlist[-1]
             result = highest[1]
       return result

             movieList = [("Finding Dory", 486), ("Captain America: Civil                      

             War", 408), ("Deadpool", 363), ("Zootopia", 341), ("Rogue One", 529), ("The  Secret Life of Pets", 368), ("Batman v Superman", 330), ("Sing", 268), ("Suicide Squad", 325), ("The Jungle Book", 364)]
             print(findMaxSales(movieList))
```

output --> Rogue One

Comment: A couple of thoughts: This doesn't actually answer the question (how to get a list sorted by a value in the tuple); You could unpack the tuple directly in your loop (for movie, value in listoftuples: ); you've overridden the type 'tuple'; And it can actually be done is a single list comprehension: (return sorted((value, movie) for movie, value in listoftuples)[-1][1])

Comment: I appreciate what you're going for, but I would argue that it lacks elegance and could be improved. Generally it would be considered poor practice to transform the order of elements in a tupple like this. I think the points about list comprehension and unpacking tupples would still stand. And I would discourage anyone using this methodology over the accepted answer.

Comment: I am incapable and could not get the code you posted to work, most likely a user error

Comment: but changed it a bit and no doubt your answer is 200x better.

Comment: def findMaxSales(listoftuples):
    newlist = sorted((value,movies) for movies, value in listoftuples)
    return newlist[-1][1]
    
    
    
    

movieList = [("Finding Dory", 486), ("Captain America: Civil War", 408), ("Deadpool", 363), ("Zootopia", 341), ("Rogue One", 529),("The Secret Life of Pets", 368), ("Batman v Superman", 330), ("Sing", 268), ("Suicide Squad", 325), ("The Jungle Book", 364)]

print(findMaxSales(movieList))