# Sorting file in ascending order by number value seperated by delimiter

Tags: python

I've got a file where each line is in the following format: string, number

For example:

```
whats up, 843

peace out, 23

hello, 91

hi, 11

see ya later, 5
```

I would like to order the file in ascending order, by the number value on the right side of the comma.

For example:

```
see ya later, 5

hi, 11

peace out, 23

hello, 91

whats up, 843
```

I know in python you can use the sorted() method to sort a list of numbers in ascending order, but I'm not exactly sure how I would extract the number on the right side of the comma and sort the file.

Comment: ... and what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: After you come up with a function that extracts the number, use it as a [key](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted()` :

```
>>> s="""whats up, 843
... 
... peace out, 23
... 
... hello, 91
... 
... hi, 11
... 
... see ya later, 5"""

>>> l=[i for i in s.split('\n') if i]
>>> l
['whats up, 843', 'peace out, 23', 'hello, 91', 'hi, 11', 'see ya later, 5']
>>> print '\n'.join(sorted(l,key=lambda x : int(x.split()[-1])))
see ya later, 5
hi, 11
peace out, 23
hello, 91
whats up, 843
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a list of tuples. You can use a similar solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459231/sort-tuples-based-on-second-parameter) for the final sorting. However, you first need to get your data file into this list of tuples.

```
data = []
for line in open('test.txt'):
    data.append((line.split(",")[0].strip(),int(line.split(",")[1].strip())))

data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

print data
```

What this does is read in each line, and split it on the comma (`,`). Extra spaces around the first element are stripped and the second element is converted to an integer. Then, we sort the list.

This outputs the following list:

```
[
    ('see ya later', 5), 
    ('hi', 11), 
    ('peace out', 23), 
    ('hello', 91), 
    ('whats up', 843)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To use sorted it is sorted(dict1, key=dict1.get)

If you print that, as I did below, it should work perfectly.

```
def test():
    testList = {"whats up": 843, "peace out": 23, "hello": 91, "hi": 11, "see ya later": 5}
    print(sorted(testList, key=testList.get))
```

Comment: Calling a dictionary `testList` is strange. Just keep types out of your variable names.