# How to rank product and price on python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to put a list of groceries into python and then ranking them with the lowest price being first. Does anyone know how I could display this so the result would look like:

```
Popcorn: 1.23
Eggs: 3.77
Water: 4.34
Milk: 7.12
Toast: 8.45
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
price_list = [["Eggs", "3.77"], ["Toast", "8.45"], ["Milk", "7.12"], ["Water", "4.34"], ["Popcorn", "1.23"]]
print("Original order: ", price_list)
price_list.sort()
print("Sorted Order: ", price_list)
```

Comment: boo you didn't even google it

Comment: `sorted(price_list, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort tuples based on second parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459231/sort-tuples-based-on-second-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

```
price_list = [["Eggs", "3.77"], ["Toast", "8.45"], ["Milk", "7.12"], ["Water", "4.34"], ["Popcorn", "1.23"]]
print("Original order: ", price_list)
print("Sorted Order: ", sorted(price_list, key=lambda x: float(x[1])))
```

Comment: hmmmm seems to give the right result. So why the downvote?